# Working with back_populates fields in flask-admin and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Consider a simple many-to-one model like this:

```py
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('entity_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    persons = relationship('Person', back_populates='entity')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('person_seq'), primary_key=True)
    entity_key = Column(ForeignKey('entity.id'), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    entity = relationship('Entity', back_populates='persons')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

In other words, many persons belong to one entity.

If you use a flask-admin view like this:

```
admin.add_view(ModelView(Entity, db.session))
```

You might get a list like this:
[image: flask-admin list]

Editing one of these entries can produce this output:
[image: flask-admin edit screen]

This presents some problems:

1. The `persons` field can be very large and take a long time to fill and probably needs to be paginated, but I can't find a way in flask-admin to cause that pagination.
2. Individual `persons` can be deleted (via the "x") but that violates the database `nullable` constraint on the column. It seems like flask-admin shouldn't allow that by default, or there should be a way to control it.
3. The `persons` are formatted via the `__str__` attribute, but it may be necessary to format them some other way, but I can't find a way in flask-admin to do that.

What do you do in flask-admin to address these problems?